# Add Component to View React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, native

I am fairly new to React Native, so excuse some of the bad practices you might see (Please point them out).

I am currently trying to dynamically load buttons in a React Component after it has mounted. The reason why I do this, I call an API as soon as the component loads that requests an array that has the values that I need to display to the user.

I have managed to retrieve the array and also loop over it, but I didn't manage to display the buttons on the current screen.

The code I have is this:

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            token : "",
            unique_id : Constants.deviceId,
            qr_value : props.route.params.random_value,
            buttons : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.testToken();
    }
```

After which, I have the render function that creates a View and calls the getButtons() function

```
    render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.header} >
                     {this.getButtons()}
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
```

The getButtons function calls the API I mentioned above, retrieves an array of Objects and assigns the value of the array to this.state.buttons. I've removed the values from the request.

```
getButtons(token) {
        fetch('link hidden', {
            method: 'POST',
        }).then(response => response.json().then(data =>({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        })
        ).then(res => {
              this.state.buttons = res.data.options;
//              this.buttons = this.state.buttons.map((item, key) =>
//                  console.log(item)
//              );
              this.renderButtons();
        }));
    }
```

The renderButtons function then calls these:

```
renderButton(button) {
      return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style = {{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
                onPress = {
                    () => this.generateToken()
                }
            >
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{button.value}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            );
      }

    renderButtons = buttons => {
        return this.state.buttons.map((button, i) => {
        return (
                <View key={i}>
                    {this.renderButton(button)}
                </View>
                );
        });
    }
```

Any help or suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: The render method isn't supposed to run fetch commands and the like. Move loading the buttons into `componentDidMount()`, and use `this.setState({ buttons: res.data.options });` to properly update state (which causes a re-render). In your render() method, use `{this.renderButtons()}` instead. (Managing/updating your component's state and displaying it via render() should be completely independent of each other)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This actually works now. 

I have another question which you might know the answer to. Is there a way to reset a state value when a user goes back to a screen? Basically, the application loads with a QR Scanner, user scans the QR, gets some options, selects one and then he is supposed to go back to the QR Scanner component. However, the this.state.scanned value stays true from the previous scan. I would need it to go back to false in order to trigger another scan event.

Comment: If this is a case of sending a message from childA to childB, the answer is to lift up the state to a common parent. Now you can pass the state as prop to childB, and pass a function that sets the state as prop to childA. In general we don't do follow ups though, especially not in comments. Look for existing solutions, do research, search using Google and on stackoverflow, and if you're positive there's no existing answer, open a new question.

Comment: You should also check if your QRScanner component's `componentDidMount` gets called again, because that's likely the case and also the perfect place to init/reset the state.